# What do weapon prefixes like "Botkiller" and "Killstreak" mean?

Tags: team-fortress-2

When playing TF2, I sometimes see people with weapons such as "Botkiller Killstreak Black Box" and then a number of kills that this person has with this particular weapon. How do I enable killcounts on my weapons, and what do the "names" (i.e. Botkiller, server-clearing etc) mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These prefixes are the quality (or actually also the type) of a weapon.

Currently there are 12 of these qualities.

- **Normal**: Stock weapons
- **Unique**: Dropped, Crafted,... weapons
- **Vintage**: The weapon was obtained before the *Mann-Conomy Update*
- **Genuine**: The weapon was obtained through cross-game promotion
- **Strange**: The weapon counts the kills. Usually obtained from a Crate
- **Unusual**: Adds a particle effect to the item. Rare drop from a Crate
- **Collector**'s: Items that were obtained with a special Chemistry set.
- **Haunted**: Halloween Update items obtained in certain parts of Halloween maps.
- **Decorated**: Unique weapon skins obtainable from campaign contracts.
- **Community**: "Given to valuable Community Contributors"
- **Self-Made**: The weapon has been made by the owner
- **Valve**: This quality is given to Valve employees

If the weapon counts the kills it is a so called strange weapon. You only get such weapons by open crates or trading. The names for example server-clearing is the rank of the weapon. The rank gets higher if the weapon has more kills. You can find all ranks [here](https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Strange).

If it is a killstreak weapon, the weapon and the eyes are shining in a defined color. More kills mean a greater shine effect.

A Botkiller weapon is a special stock weapon. Such weapons have a robotic head hanging on the weapon. To obtained a Botkiller weapon you have to complete a "Tour of Duty". Read more [here](https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Botkiller_weapons).

<sub>Information from TF2 [wiki](https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Item_quality).</sub>

Comment: @imulsion Your welcome :3

Comment: "Botkiller" is not a rank, but indicates that the weapon is a reskin earned in Mann Versus Machine (http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Botkiller_weapons). "Killstreak" is also not a rank, but is earned by applying a killstreak kit to the weapon. A killstreak weapon will have some colored effect when the player gets a killstreak (http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Killstreak_Kit).

Comment: @AustinMohr I don't see anywhere in Gerret's answer does he say Botkiller is a rank; I think you're misinterpreting his answer.

Comment: Do note that not all Strange weapons use the same ranks: Sapper, Holiday Punch, and a few others have their own ranks.  Also, Strange Filters exist that make a Strange only count on certain maps and also give it a map-specific name.

Comment: @Powerlord could you perhaps provide examples of these certain ranks and names for the specific maps? I have never heard of this.

Comment: @howdareyou: He asked the question _"What do 'botkiller' and 'killstreak' mean"_ with _"Strange weapon names are the rank of the weapon"_.  I'd say that implies he **did** make that claim, making this answer incorrect _(and even if you think he's not saying that, then this answer would be off-topic)_.  So -1 from me.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft The question was edited! (check dates) Nevertheless I edited the answer to fit the question.

Answer (score 3):

The prefixes only show a difference of a weapon compared to its normal counterpart. There are many that exist and most of the time, they boost the price of items.

- **Strange** is given to weapons that have been uncrated or modified (e.g. strange bacon grease). These show the amount of kills you got with the weapon and changes to other words/phrases when different goals have been reached. Strange Weapons also can have Strange parts added onto them. 
  Vintage was added to items that were crafted with 'too expensive' recipes after they became cheaper.
- **Genuine** are given through participation in specific events.
- **Australium**/**Golden** and **Killstreak**: Australium weapons are obtains through a rare chance of completing the two cities tour.

  - These can also give you killstreak kit which can change the weapons into killstreak weapons. Specialised and Professional killstreak qualities are gotten through fabricators which give the kit for the specific quality and item. Those are very expensive.
- **Killstreak** gives cool effects (specialised or professional only) and a killstreak counter. Also Increases price.
- **Botkiller** can be done similar to the previous one but with the other tours.
- **Collector's** quality is gotten through Chemistry Sets gotten from random drops. Those sets must then be used with other specific items to get the item to be collector's quality.
- **Haunted** is given to items obtained from Halloween events.
- **Unusual** is given to hats that can be uncrated, unusual hats are extremely rare.
- **Festive** given to weapons uncrated from Smissmas crates.
- **Decorated** is given to unique weapons skins obtainable from the Gun Mettle Update. This quality comes in six grades of rarity and is further modified by five levels of wear.

There are other qualities that generally aren't obtainable outside of a few specific cases as well:

- **Valve** means the wearer of the item is a Valve employee.
- **Community** means they have contributed a lot to TF2.
- **Self-Made** means the wearer created that item through the Steam workshop

In conclusion: Strange, Festive, Vintage, Genuine, Collector's, Unusual, Haunted, Botkiller or Australium increase price.

More info on: https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Quality